# Jupyter Notebook Ignores 'm' and 'v', 'd' Key Inputs in `input()` Function

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press 'm' or 'v or 'd', the expected behavior (typing the character into the `input()` field) doesn't happen. Instead it just acts as if im in command mode and does the shortcut key command. For instance if i run:

input()

and i type in 'm' in the input field the cell just turns into a markdown and i have to interupt the kernel to stop.

similarly for 'd': instead of actually inputing the 'd' it just deletes the cell im working in."

Im confused has anyone experienced a similar problem?

What I tried:
-This issue is present even after trying in a new Conda environment with a fresh Jupyter installation.

- I've confirmed that I'm in Edit Mode, not Command Mode. The problem occurs when the cell is running and waiting for input.
- Using other browsers and incognito mode doesn't solve the issue.
- Browser extensions that could potentially interfere have been ruled out.
- Keyboard settings have been checked, and no other applications seem to be capturing these keystrokes.